# how to monitor CPU frequency reliably ( in linux)?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, cpu, hardware, frequency

I am tying to monitor the CPU operating frequencies for individual cores. I am not sure what's the correct way to monitor the CPU frequency both form the kernel level and hardware level reliably with less overhead.

I would highly appreciate if someone could answer couple of questions that I have.

Let's say I am running an application by pinning it on to a core. I would like to monitor whats the frequency it demands during its execution phase (start to end) and capture it. I would want the accurate frequency that it demands from the hardware level (from MSR's might be).

Not sure what's the accurate way to capture this? Is there a way? Are there any tools or command via which I can read the frequency value directly from the MSR's?

I have tried couple of options, not sure if this reflects the correct frequency:

NOTE: I am trying to sample the core's frequency every 10ms, 20ms, 30ms, ..... and so on.

from the kernel level:

1. I was reading a sysfs file:

cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq

Not sure if the above gives the correct frequency value every 10ms, 20ms, etc. Is there any overhead associated by reading this file every 10ms time interval?

2. Then I was using turbostat command, but this does not tell me what the correct frequency is for a particular core on a specified time interval but rather tells me the busy% etc, but I am looking for an accurate frequency for the sampling time interval that I specify

Questions:

1. Whats the best and reliable way to monitor CPU frequency from a systems perspective with very low overhead?
2. Whats the minimum sampling interval time that I can use to monitor CPU frequency (I know this depends on the CPU governors). I am currently assuming and interested for Ondemand power governor being set for the core which I am trying to monitor the CPU frequency.

It would be a great help if someone could guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to track all changes between cpu frequencies on application event basis, not the summary which those sysfs provides:

cpufreq have trace points to track - trace_cpu_frequency(),
and you can add additional custom trace points to track your application's event - e.g. write messages to trace/trace_marker.
you can see the all events recorded including cpufreq TPs and your trace marks after execution.